# Highcharts custom SVG marker

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want to render a custom SVG as a point on my chart, but it's not working properly.
The point is only visible on hover.
I have tried different code examples, but the result is always the same.
Tried different chart types, different browsers. If I use a native symbol, it works fine.

[image]

```
const Chart: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.cross = function (x: any, y: any, w: any, h: any) {
    return ['M', x, y, 'L', x + w, y + h, 'M', x + w, y, 'L', x, y + h, 'z'];
  };

  const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        data: [
          {
            x: 1,
            y: 1,
            color: 'black',
            marker: {
              symbol: 'cross',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `marker.lineWidth` and the `marker.lineColor` to display the marker.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-snbxaw?file=index.js

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that ^^